# Triggering get and set for properties using attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I need to build an attribute that will override the getter and the setter of an property. To be more clear, here is how it works today and how it should work using the attribute (the result should be the same).

Old version:

```
public class A
{
    private Handle _handle;

    public String StringProp 
    {
        get {
            return _handle.GetProperty(PropId.StringProp);
        }
        set {
            _handle.SetProperty(PropId.StringProp, value);
        }
    }

    public int IntProp 
    {
        get {
            return _handle.GetProperty(PropId.IntProp);
        }
        set {
            _handle.SetProperty(PropId.IntProp, value);
        }
    }
}
```

New version:

```
public class A
{
    private Handle _handle;

    [HandleProperty(PropId.StringProp)]
    public String StringProp { get; set; }

    [HandleProperty(PropId.IntProp)]
    public int IntProp { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute `HandleProperty` should known to link the getter and setter to `_handle.GetProperty` and `_handle.SetProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

I created two enums and some of the fields in one enum were mapped to another enums fields using attributes. I think you can do something like this...

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public sealed class MapsToAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string Text;

    public string MapsToText
    {
        get
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }

    public MapsToAttribute(string mapsToText)
    {
        Text = mapsToText;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```